# Text in help tag not getting displayed

Tags: python

I have sample below code:

```
commandParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Applications Management Operation', add_help = True)
commandParser.add_argument('-ssl', required = False, default = False, dest = 'sslEnabled', help = 'SSL Enabled')
args = commandParser.parse_known_args()[0]
commandParser.add_argument('-t', required = False, default = getDefaultTEAServerURL(args.sslEnabled), dest = 'serverURL', help = 'TEA Server URL')
commandParser.add_argument('-u', required = True, dest = 'userName', help = 'TEA User Name')
commandParser.add_argument('-p', required = True, dest = 'userPwd', help = 'TEA User Password')
commandParser.add_argument('-sc', required = False, default = '', dest = 'serverCert', help = 'Server certificate Path')
commandParser.add_argument('-cc', required = False, default = '', dest = 'clientCert', help = 'Client certificate Path')
```

When I run like

```
 python applicationsMgmt.py --help
```

I get below

```
usage: applicationsMgmt.py [-h] [-ssl SSLENABLED]

Applications Management Operations CLI.

optional arguments:
 -h, --help       show this help message and exit
 -ssl SSLENABLED  SSL Enabled
```

Why other help texts not getting displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you do `commandParser.parse_known_args()[0]` you can't add more arguments. Since you are using the fact if ssl is enabled or not in the next parser argument, I would suggest putting in the default value in to `getDefaultTEAServerURL(args.sslEnabled)`, since you cannot access that. Another option, would be to do something like this

```
if args.serverURL == "":
   server_url = getDefaultTEAServerURL(args.sslEnabled)
```

And then change the default of server_url to `""`

Comment: Thnx for your suggestion. I did that and that works. I was really looking if we have some option from python, without me putting some extra logic.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code `args = commandParser.parse_known_args()[0]` to the bottom.

```
commandParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Applications Management Operation', add_help = True)
commandParser.add_argument('-ssl', required = False, default = False, dest = 'sslEnabled', help = 'SSL Enabled')
commandParser.add_argument('-t', required = False, default = getDefaultTEAServerURL(args.sslEnabled), dest = 'serverURL', help = 'TEA Server URL')
commandParser.add_argument('-u', required = True, dest = 'userName', help = 'TEA User Name')
commandParser.add_argument('-p', required = True, dest = 'userPwd', help = 'TEA User Password')
commandParser.add_argument('-sc', required = False, default = '', dest = 'serverCert', help = 'Server certificate Path')
commandParser.add_argument('-cc', required = False, default = '', dest = 'clientCert', help = 'Client certificate Path')
args = commandParser.parse_known_args()[0]
# or
# args = commandParser.parse_args()
```

Comment: I cannot. I need it in next line, for function getDefaultTEAServerURL(args.sslEnabled)